# Converting number 0123456 to string without losing 0

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, converters

I need to convert 012345 to '012345'. toString() and String() removes 0. How can I reserve it?

The reason I am asking is because of this question: 
Write a JavaScript program that accepts a number as input and insert
dashes (-) between each two even numbers. For example if you accept 025468 the output should be 0-254-6-8.

Comment: Put it back after converting?

Comment: This seems very similar to this older question. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559021/javascript-number-preserve-leading-0

Comment: Your question is unclear. `'012345'` is already a string and `'012345'.toString()` yields the same string, `'012345'`. See for yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/x3a7pn7x/

Comment: Hi jordan, you misunderstood. that period is the sentence period. There is a space between . and toString()

Comment: @Abi, those are java solutions. my tag is javascript

Comment: You're trying to solve the wrong problem. If the user enters `025468` into an `<input>` then it's already a string. You'll only lose that leading `0` if you try to convert it to a number. Don't convert the whole string into a number—treat the string as a series of characters, and as you read each character you can convert it to a number to test whether or not it's even.

Comment: oh! I missed the word "as input". Thanks for pointing that out. If you rewrite that as answer, i will accept it

Comment: @RobG but the linked question won't answer the second part of the question.

Comment: for the second part `console.log("025468".replace(/([02468])(?=[02468])/g, "$1-"))`